# namespace schema for urn:uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882

Tags: xml, xsd, ado, xml-namespaces

The XML Schema Definition for an XML file generated on a Microsoft platform
imports the namespace `uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882`. However I
am unable to find the XML schema definition for the elements associated with
this namespace.

Comment: It seems the namespace of a XSD generated on-the-fly by some tool - e.g. from a database schema